# How to store array names in array in VBA

Tags: arrays, vba

I have a list of arrays. I am looping through to write the data in the arrays into a text file. When I loop through each time, I would like to use a different array to access the data.

I am thinking of storing the names of these arrays in an different array and as I loop through, I can access this array using the current loop index. But I am not sure how to do this in VBA.

Need some guidance on this. I am welcome to other suggestions as well.

Comment: Show the code you have so far.

Comment: I have the idea not don't know how to implement it.

Comment: Just use a multidimensional array - `Dim arrays(1 To 5, 1 To 20) As String` which will effectively create an array of 5 arrays, with 20 items each

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also store them in a collection. This will also allow you to add a key to each array that you store in the collection. You can than even call a specific array using this key. Just a short example to get you started:

```
Sub CreateCollection()
Dim col As Collection
Dim arr As Variant
Dim MyArray1(1) As String
Dim MyArray2(1) As String

MyArray1(0) = "FirstItemArr1"
MyArray1(1) = "SecondItemArr1"
MyArray2(0) = "FirstItemArr2"
MyArray2(1) = "SecondItemArr2"
Set col = New Collection
col.Add MyArray1, "ArrayName1"
col.Add MyArray2, "ArrayName2"
For Each arr In col
    Debug.Print arr(1)
Next
Debug.Print col("ArrayName2")(1)
Set col = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: This is adding the data, how do u retrieve it?

Comment: Just edited my answer. Gives you both retrieval method. For Each is always nice to cycle through all values. col("<arrayname>") is handy to call an array by name (or key to be precise). Added the set col = nothing to destroy the collection when I no longer need is, just good practice.